# HandMotion Animation doesnt disable after plane has been discovered (ARCore)

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am using plane discovery in the augmented image sceneform example. So my new session configuration is like this in the AugmentedImageFragment -

```
getPlaneDiscoveryController().show();
getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null); //default handMotion animation appears
getArSceneView().getPlaneRenderer().setEnabled(true);
```

But when a plane is discovered the HandMotion animation still persist. I confirmed if the planes are being detected, and they are. Not sure why the animation stays. Is there any way to explicitly disable the animation in code ?